# How to disable or enable all child widgets inside a common parent in the right way in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a GUI made by PyQt5. On this GUI, there is a push button and a frame which includes several radio buttons as illustrated below:

[image: My GUI]

I want to change the (enabled/disabled) states of the radio buttons in the frame every time I click the push button. Since the frame is the parent of the radio buttons, I think this could be achieved by disabling or enabling the frame when the push button is clicked. Below is the code in my `m_view.py` module and my `main_window.py` module:

m_view.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

from main_window import Ui_Form

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.destroyed.connect(sys.exit)
    self.pushButtonOK.clicked.connect(self._update_status_of_frame)

  def _update_status_of_frame(self):
    status = self.frame.isEnabled()
    self.frame.setEnabled(not status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main_window.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_window.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(176, 264)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/ORing_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Form.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.labelForItems = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelForItems.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelForItems.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelForItems.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.labelForItems.setFont(font)
        self.labelForItems.setStyleSheet("")
        self.labelForItems.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.labelForItems.setObjectName("labelForItems")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelForItems, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setEnabled(False)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.radioButton_a = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.radioButton_a.setEnabled(False)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_a.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_a.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_a.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.radioButton_a.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_a.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_a.setObjectName("radioButton_a")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Form)
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.setObjectName("buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.setExclusive(False)
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.addButton(self.radioButton_a)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_a)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setFont(font)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setText("")
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setObjectName("labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120)
        self.radioButton_b = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_b.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_b.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_b.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.radioButton_b.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_b.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_b.setObjectName("radioButton_b")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.addButton(self.radioButton_b)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_b)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setFont(font)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setText("")
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setObjectName("labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120)
        self.radioButton_c = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_c.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_c.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_c.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.radioButton_c.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_c.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_c.setObjectName("radioButton_c")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.addButton(self.radioButton_c)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_c)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setFont(font)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setText("")
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setObjectName("labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(74, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonOK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButtonOK.setFont(font)
        self.pushButtonOK.setObjectName("pushButtonOK")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonOK, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButtonOK, self.radioButton_a)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.radioButton_a, self.radioButton_b)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.radioButton_b, self.radioButton_c)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Tool"))
        self.labelForItems.setText(_translate("Form", "Items:"))
        self.radioButton_a.setText(_translate("Form", "A"))
        self.radioButton_b.setText(_translate("Form", "B"))
        self.radioButton_c.setText(_translate("Form", "C"))
        self.pushButtonOK.setText(_translate("Form", "OK"))
```

However, the outcome did not turn out to be what I expected. The radio button at the top of the frame always remains in the disabled state though the other two radio buttons at the bottom could be disabled or enabled as I wish.

[image: The radio button at the top of the frame remains disabled.]

Can anyone kindly explain to me why? And how I should fix it?

Comment: That's because you *explicitly* disabled the button. Toggling the enabled state of the parent doesn't override an explicit disabled state of the children. If you want to automatically reset the enabled state of the children, you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your reply. I revise my code based on your answer. And it works as I expect. I will post the revised version of my code below.

Answer (score 0):

I revise my code based on the answer of musicamante. And it works. Below is the revised version of my code:

m_view.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

from main_window import Ui_Form

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):

  def __init__(self, parent = None):

    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.destroyed.connect(sys.exit)
    self.pushButtonOK.clicked.connect(self._update_state_of_radio_btns)

  def _update_state_of_radio_btns(self):

    radioBtnsAsList = self.frame.findChildren(QtWidgets.QRadioButton)
    for radioBtn in radioBtnsAsList:
        state = radioBtn.isEnabled()
        radioBtn.setEnabled(not state)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main_window.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_window_2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(176, 264)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/ORing_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Form.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.labelForItems = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelForItems.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelForItems.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelForItems.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.labelForItems.setFont(font)
        self.labelForItems.setStyleSheet("")
        self.labelForItems.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.labelForItems.setObjectName("labelForItems")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelForItems, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.radioButton_a = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        self.radioButton_a.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_a.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_a.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_a.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.radioButton_a.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_a.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_a.setObjectName("radioButton_a")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Form)
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.setObjectName("buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.setExclusive(False)
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.addButton(self.radioButton_a)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_a)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setFont(font)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setText("")
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120.setObjectName("labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAndStatusStatusForRX120)
        self.radioButton_b = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_b.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_b.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_b.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.radioButton_b.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_b.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_b.setObjectName("radioButton_b")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.addButton(self.radioButton_b)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_b)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setFont(font)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setText("")
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120.setObjectName("labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelToDisplayCopperLinkActAnd100MStatusForRX120)
        self.radioButton_c = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.radioButton_c.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.radioButton_c.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.radioButton_c.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.radioButton_c.setFont(font)
        self.radioButton_c.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton_c.setObjectName("radioButton_c")
        self.buttonGroupForIOChkOfIGCS_RX120GT.addButton(self.radioButton_c)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_c)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setFont(font)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setText("")
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120.setObjectName("labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelToDisplaySFP1GStatusForRX120)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(74, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButtonOK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButtonOK.setFont(font)
        self.pushButtonOK.setObjectName("pushButtonOK")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonOK, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButtonOK, self.radioButton_a)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.radioButton_a, self.radioButton_b)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.radioButton_b, self.radioButton_c)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Tool"))
        self.labelForItems.setText(_translate("Form", "Items:"))
        self.radioButton_a.setText(_translate("Form", "A"))
        self.radioButton_b.setText(_translate("Form", "B"))
        self.radioButton_c.setText(_translate("Form", "C"))
        self.pushButtonOK.setText(_translate("Form", "OK"))
```